# Ionic generate pdf in iOS and android

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

Can anyone help me with this issue ?. I found a lot of information on google, jspdf, pdfmake.org among others, inappbrowser plugins, but I have not done anything to make me ionic function.

The idea would be a short form for refilling for example four form fields (name, address, telephone), and clicking on a button that can be downloaded or viewed on the device that page information filled in .pdf ... or image even if ...

Thanks for the help, I'm a little desperate :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for our company app we use ngpdf-viewer: it allows you to serve a pdf document to your device and view just like opening it natively.
Check it out here: http://ngmodules.org/modules/ng-pdfviewer

I put the ngpdf-viewer inside of a ion scroll so that the user can pinch zoom, and scroll the document easily.

Check out the github here for usage and examples: https://github.com/akrennmair/ng-pdfviewer

Comment: Hi, thanks this works! I've built a basic app in ionic, compiled with phonegap builder online, tested on android and iOS and it worked ... But I also need to generate PDF from a form of data passed through scope ... I saw this repo (https://github.com/SajithDulanjaya/HTML2PDF), you think that could be mixed to generate the pdf and then visualize it with ng-PDFViewer to such a scroll which I have done in the example? Can you think of another way? Cheers!

Comment: It is pretty much not possible to generate a pdf from form inputs, or at lease not very feasible to build a system from scratch. You can use a third party company like https://rightsignature.com/ to accomplish this. The company I work for uses them and it works really well. I don't know how well it will intergrate with mobile by they have a pretty extensive api